# Can't Get PHP RegEx to Match / and - Literals

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre

I am using regexs to match link objects in my template files. Basically, a link is identified, and it is either translated to javascript or HTML depending on if the user has JS enabled.

Here is what a sample link looks like:

```
<div id="someDiv">{_LINK_9_link text here_noclass_noid_}</div>
```

And here is the regex that I use to find these objects within the code:

```
$linkExp = '/\{_LINK_([0-9]+)_([a-z0-9 ]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_\}/i';
```

As it sits, this code works fine to do an example like the one above, where the link text can contain letters, numbers, or spaces. However, when I try to add a `/` or `-` to the link text, I can't get the regex to work anymore.

Here is what I tried:

```
<!-- html link code -->
<div id="someDiv">{_LINK_9_tips/suggestions_noclass_noid_}</div>
// php link expression
$linkExp = '/\{_LINK_([0-9]+)_([a-z0-9 \/\-]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_\}/i';
```

But it still couldn't find a match because of the `/`. If I take the slash out, it works fine. Any idea on how to match a literal `/` or `-` in a regex? It would be nice to allow even more characters than letters, numbers, spaces, hyphens, or slashes, but I'm a novice at regexs so I don't really know what I'm doing. If someone could help me fix it so that it would match anything for the link text (even symbols, such as &, %, $, etc.), that would be very much appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `[0-9] = [\d]` 2. `[a-Z0-9] = [\w]`

Comment: Your second regex matches the html just fine for me .. how are you using it?

Comment: Echoing @ExplosionPills, [it works for me](http://so.viper-7.com/XwUmmP)

Comment: @DreamEater `\w` also includes underscores, and depending upon the locale it can include other letter characters (latter is probably not an issue)

Comment: Are you _allowed_ to include a literal space in your character class like that?  I'd be inclined to represent that as `\x20`.

Comment: @Sepster, yes a literal space character is absolutely fine.

Comment: Why not use `$linkExp = '/\{_LINK_(\d+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_\}/i';`

Comment: @salathe I learn something new every day! :-)  Re the question about matching `-` literal, including this at the very start or end of a character class as you have will work OK (ie it won't indicate a 'range' in this case). Re `/`, you can avoid needing to escape it (for clarity) by using a different regex delimiter at the start and end of your regex as per [PCRE delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 1):

You were almost right, use

```
$linkExp = '/\{_LINK_([0-9]+)_([a-z0-9 \/-]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z0-9]+)_\}/i';
```

1. The '-' is used inside [ ] to range, for example [a-z], but if it is put at the end, it is regarded as one more character, for example [a-z-] will match letters + '-'